# problem in playing next song in the avaudioplayer

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

my delegate method looks like this. after the first song is played it goes into this method and plays the second song , however when the second song is done playing it stops. it does not go into the delegate method.i need to play all the songs continuously.   i am not sure, why. can someone help me.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)p successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
 if (flag == NO)
  NSLog(@"Playback finished unsuccessfully");
 else
 {
  //[player stop];
  index++;
  NSLog(@"%d",index);
  path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[songlist objectAtIndex:index] ofType:@"mp3"];
  [player initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
  [songlabel2 setTitle:[songlist objectAtIndex:index]];

  [endtime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[player duration]/100]];
  [player play];
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re not defining a local variable called `player`, I’m assuming that `player` is an instance variable that was used to play the first song, and you’ve created it with

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:firstSongURL error:&error];
```

or something similar, and you’ve set the delegate. In your `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: successfully:` method, you have

```
[player initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
```

which means you’re sending `-initWithContentsOfURL:error:` again to the same instance. **Do not call an initialiser twice on a given object.** The results are unpredictable and there is potential for memory leaking. You should release the previous instance of AVAudioPlayer, e.g.

```
[player release];
```

and then create a new instance with `+alloc` and `-initWithContentsOfURL:error:` again, just like you did with the first song, and set the appropriate delegate:

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:secondSongURL error:&error];
player.delegate = self;
[player play];
```

Comment: thanks buddy.. i will try this tomorrow and let you know the result.

Comment: Hello Bavarious, it worked . i just set the delegate i did not do the release. thank you so much. but i am having another problem. once i pressed the home button the app goes away and when clicked on the app icon 2 songs play at the same time. not sure why this is happening.

Comment: If you don’t release the instance and create another one, there is potential for memory leaking and unpredictable side effects. Please do it.